# Unable to load validation.xml in struts2

Tags: xml, validation, struts2

I am new to struts2. I am trying to validate a form using xml file. I am showing code which is related to only registration. My project has so many other files which are not related now. Here is my form

```
<s:form action="registerOphthalmologist" method="post" validate="true">   
    <s:textfield    key="username"      label="Choose UserName" required="true"/>
    <s:password     key="password"      label="Choose Password" required="true"/>
    <s:submit       value="Register"    align="center"/>
</s:form>
```

This is my struts.xml where I am using wildcards

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="messages" />

<package name="validation" extends="struts-default">    
<action name="register*" class="com.ActionClasses.RegisterAction">
    <result name="success"> /login.jsp              </result>
    <result name="input">   /register{1}.jsp        </result>
</action> 
</package>
</struts2>
```

In my RegisterAction.java I am using a model class where all my beans are stored

```
public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport implements Action,ModelDriven<RegisterBeans>
{
RegisterBeans registerBeans = new RegisterBeans();  
public String execute() throws Exception{
   if(RegisterDao.save(registerBeans) > 0) /*For every registration 4 tables will be filled in database*/
       return SUCCESS;
   return ERROR;
}
@Override
public RegisterBeans getModel() {
    return registerBeans;
}
}
```

RegisterDao will keep the data in database and returns 1. This is working fine. Here is my model class RegisterBeans.java

```
public class RegisterBeans extends ActionSupport{

private String username;
private String password;

\\getters & setter
}
```

RegisterAction-validation.xml This is placed under same folder where RegisterAction.java is placed

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
      "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">  

<validators>

     <validator type="requiredstring" short-circuit="true"> <!-- If username is not present in the form , further validation don't take place because of short-circuit-->
        <param name="fieldName">registerBeans.username</param>
        <message>First name is required.</message>
     </validator>

    <field name="registerBeans.password">
       <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>You must enter password</message>
        </field-validator>
        <field-validator type="stringlength">
            <param name="minLength">6</param>
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>Password length should be minimum of 6 characters</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>

</validators>
```

Everything is working fine when there is no error in input. The problem is When I don't give any input and presses submit button. Then also everything is working fine. That means data is being inserted into database. There is no error showing on the JSP. The message in my console is

```
SEVERE: Caught exception while loading file com/ActionClasses/RegisterAction-validation.xml
struts.apache.org - Class: java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl
File: AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java
Method: connect
Line: 184 - java/net/AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184:-1
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:123)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidatorFileParser.parseActionValidatorConfigs(ValidatorFileParser.java:54)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.loadFile(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:361)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildClassValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:252)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:340)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.getValidators(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:69)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.getValidators(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:49)
at org.apache.struts2.components.Form.getValidators(Form.java:419)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.invokeMethod(BeansWrapper.java:616)
at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.exec(SimpleMethodModel.java:113)
at freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:93)
at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:87)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196)
at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:160)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:351)
at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:95)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196)
at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:79)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196)
at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:1375)
at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:155)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196)
at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:196)
at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:176)
at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:232)
at org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.renderTemplate(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:168)
at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.mergeTemplate(UIBean.java:530)
at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:484)
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:43)
at org.apache.jsp.registerOphthalmologist_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(registerOphthalmologist_jsp.java:271)
at org.apache.jsp.registerOphthalmologist_jsp._jspService(registerOphthalmologist_jsp.java:114)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:750)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:720)
at org.apache.jsp.personalizedRegistrations_jsp._jspService(personalizedRegistrations_jsp.java:77)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:139)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:178)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:348)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:253)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:167)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:206)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:115)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:143)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:121)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:170)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:504)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: struts.apache.org
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1167)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1103)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1511)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:640)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1293)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1260)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:263)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1164)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1050)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:964)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:121)
... 187 more
```

[image: jars which I am using]jars which I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a very old version of S2; older versions either used:

- No DTD (< 2.0.8), or
- The XWork validation

This is discussed on the [S2 validation page](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/validation.html).

If you insist on using a long-deprecated version:

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
    "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
    "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
```

I would **strongly** recommend using a version released more recently.

S2.0.11 was released in 2007/2008 and for a variety of reasons should *not* be used.

There are a variety of known security and performance issues associated with these ancient versions.

Comment: That helps me but while using it I am getting a following warning ' The file cannot be validated as the XML definition "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd" that is specified as describing the syntax of the file cannot be located '. (I have given my proxy details in eclipse.)

Comment: @user130004 Check the actual DTD in the xwork jar, I don't recall what version you should be using.

Comment: I am using 'xwork-2.0.4' in which 'xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd' is present.

Comment: @user130004 Which isn't what your validation file is showing. You also need to match it with what's inside the jar's DTD, not just the file name.